# Self referencing loops with EF5 and Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, serialization

I am using MVC4 with EF5 database first and `Newtonsoft.Json` for serializing objects to JSON for example in Web API controllers.

To avoid the problem of self referencing loops i set the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` to the specific collections in my generated classes.

My problem is now that each time i update my model i have to readd the attributes to the classes.

How can i avoid that? I think i have to edit the `DBModel.tt` script? What have i to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a metadata class with the MetadataType attribute. If your generated class is:

```
public partial class MyClass{

    public string SomeProperty {get; set; }

    public string SomePropertyToIgnore {get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create a metadata class like so (in the same namespace):

```
public class MyClass_Metadata{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SomePropertyToIgnore {get; set; }
}
```

The create a partial of your generated class (in the same namespace) with the MetadatType attribute applied:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyClass_Metadata))]
public partial class MyClass{
}
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx